# My thread doesn't work with my Queue

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I'm a noob in Multi threading, so this will propably be a stupid question ;)
But I have a thread wich uses a queue that will be filled with commands while the thread is running. The problem I have here, is that the thread doesn't see the changes in the queue, and therefore keeps returning null when I am trying to acces the elements in the queue. Any help with this?

```
//This method will add an command to the queue
public void sendCommand( String Command )
{
  qe.add(Command);
}

public void run()
{
  while( true )
  {
    while(qe.peek() != null)
    {
      sendCommandToDevice(qe.poll());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention: It's Java!

Comment: Perhaps the implementation of the Queue is not using "synchronized" The Queue used is it thread safe ?

Comment: What queue class are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is some kind of problem in the implementation of your queue; I have no other explanation for why the read loop doesn't see changes.

That said, this looks like a bad way to implement this.  Your thread will 'spin', chewing up CPU at a great rate, any time it waits for messages to be added.  You need something that will notify your reader that there are (possibly) elements added to the queue, rather than polling it continuously.  Look up a tutorial on the Object methods wait and notifyAll; the basic idea is that your reader thread executes wait on an object, and that suspends the thread until it is started again with notifyAll.  The entire lesson is too big for an SO answer.

Comment: A `BlockingQueue` would be better still than mucking about with wait/notify

Comment: So it would -- that's a feature of java 6 I had not yet run across.  thanks.

Comment: Actually `BlockingQueue` is around since 5

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is Java or C#, you should mark the Queue as `volatile`. This will force the concurrently running thread to recheck the value of the queue each time it attempts to access it rather than caching the object.

If you want more information, [this post](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) does a pretty good job of explaining the keyword.

Comment: Have you ran your code with a debugger attached to trace the process? Are you sure that all of your threads are executing? If the queue is marked as volatile, changed, and then read, it should be guaranteed to be in the proper state.

Comment: I have tested this, the thread is running, and the queue is changing throughout the program, but for some reason the thread still doesn't see the change

Comment: -1 Making the queue volatile is not going to make a difference - it only guarantees that a reassignement `qe = new Queue()` will be visible, but not that additions to the queue will be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Use a thread safe queue, such as [any of the `BlockingQueue` implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), and it should solve your issue.